# CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot

Tags: redis, jedis, redis-cluster

Currently we're using single redis instance(String datastructure is used, here i am able to fetch data using "get key" and "mget key1 key2"). To scale the redis now created redis cluster here i get this error: `ERR CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot`.

If I give hashtag then all data is storing in one slot. All other slots are unused. 
I am new to redis, Please suggest a solution how to make use of all the slots. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4):

RTFM: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-clustering-best-practices-with-keys/

Keys are hashed. Using a hash forces the same hash result (aka slot) so that multiple command operations can work.